# linking images in wordpress from media library

Tags: wordpress, image

Hi i am newbie in WordPress. i tried to add images from the directory but image is not shown !! any help ?? here's my code !!

```
 <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item">
          <a href="#portfolioModal1" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
              <div class="caption">
                  <div class="caption-content">
                      <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <img src="img/profile.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
          </a>
 </div>
```

ps. i am newbie in Wordpress.

Comment: media library of wordpress? or your own image path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the image from your dir then use:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/profile.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/profile.png" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>` before image or other files

```
<div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item">
          <a href="#portfolioModal1" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
              <div class="caption">
                  <div class="caption-content">
                      <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/profile.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
          </a>
 </div>
```

Comment: what does get_template_directory_uri() function do ??

Comment: that basically locate/target the dir of the image in your theme folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wp_upload_dir](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir#Usage).

```
    <?php $media_dir = wp_upload_dir('2014/12'); ?>
    <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-item">
              <a href="#portfolioModal1" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                  <div class="caption">
                      <div class="caption-content">
                          <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x"></i>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <img src="<?php echo $media_dir['url']; ?>/profile.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
              </a>
     </div>
```

Here in above code, there is **2014/12** .So It will take you to the `wp-content > uploads > 2014 > 12` .So change it according to yours.

Comment: or he can just use a full url path of the image once its uploaded, that's much easier approach. Probably not the best one but a quick one.

Comment: But if he wants to use it repeatedly, then It is time consuming :)

Comment: Good point, but I think so far he only want 1 image to be shown so.  But won't that get all the images that's been uploaded in that folder?

Comment: No It won't.As I have mentioned in my answer, it will only fetch the image(**profile.png** in that case) which is in **2014 > 12 ** folder of the wordpress media library.

Comment: thanx .. it helped too !! but i don't need the $media_dir variable right now.. anyway thanx !!

Comment: It will be great if you learned by this cz you might need to use that in future( for sure ;) ). Happy Coding !